# How can I make the Views defined in Android XML customs view file visible

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view, custom-view

I've the below code, that is having one element as shown in the XML file below it, and a call of the `custom view` named `card`

```
package tk.zillion.app1;

import tk.zillion.app1.CustomViews.Card;

public class EmptyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_empty);
        RelativeLayout rl;
        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_empty);
        rl.addView(new Card(this));
    }
}
```

Below is the XML file, and how the layout appear in the Android studio:

[image]

The `Card` custom view is as below code and XML file:

```
package tk.zillion.app1.CustomViews;

import tk.zillion.app1.R;

public class Card extends RelativeLayout {
    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }
    public Card(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }
    private void init(Context context) {
        WindowManager windowmanager = (WindowManager) this.getContext()
                                        .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        Display display = windowmanager.getDefaultDisplay();

        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);;
        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this.getContext());
        rl.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_card_background));
        rl.setMinimumWidth(width);
        Button btn = new Button(this.getContext());
     //   btn.setId(R.id.titleId);
        btn.setId(View.generateViewId());
        TextView one = new TextView(this.getContext());
        one.setText("Device width is: "+String.valueOf(width)+", Device height is: "+String.valueOf(height));
        one.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

        btn.setText(R.string.custom);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                CharSequence text = "Hello from another toast!";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
        rl.addView(btn);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, btn.getId());
        rl.addView(one, lp);
        // or one.setLayoutParams(lp);  rl.addView(one);
        //  lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
        this.addView(rl);
    }
}
```

and the XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_view"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <tk.zillion.app1.CustomViews.Card
        android:id="@+id/custom_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        />
    </tk.zillion.app1.CustomViews.Card>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and appeared in Android studio as:

[image]

Below is how the app looks at execution (Right side), and how it should be (Left side).
The View defined in the XML file, that is the `My First App` TextView, is not appearing at the execution, while all other elements defined pragmatically are visible.

[image]

I tried to use `inflate` but did not work with me

My Question is how can I the View, the ones defined in the XML file are visible?

Comment: you try for adding view but according to relative layout it's always start to add view from x,y 0,0  you can put a gravity or reference of another view with id so you can align with another view object... @Hasan A Yousef

Comment: @Chirag.T can you give me example, I'm very new to Android programming, thansk

Comment: like `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.below_id);

viewToLayout.setLayoutParams(p);`

Comment: @Chirag.T, sorry, your answer not clear for me, do not understand what you want me to change in my code to get it done.

Comment: @Chirag.T what is the `viewToLayout`

Comment: @Chirag.T, I wrote this: `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.checkBox);
        this.setLayoutParams(p);` and got the full card moved under the `checbox` but the `TextView` defined in the XML file still not appearing.

Comment: inside card is available relative layout..? @Hasan A Yousef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, and will detailed it below, may some one in the future get help from it:

1 . there was no need for using `<tk.zillion.app1.CustomViews.Card>` so I restructured my `view_customs.xml` to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_view"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

2 . It looks I was wrongly using the inflater, so re-wote it to match the:

`inflate(XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)`inflation statement, where itInflates a new view hierarchy from the specified XML node.

3 . The final structure of my `Card` class `init` method, became:

```
private void init(Context context) {
      // 1. Define the main layout of the CARD class
      RelativeLayout cardLayout = new RelativeLayout(this.getContext());

     // 2. (Optional) set the require specs for this Layout
    cardLayout.setBackground(
              context.getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_card_background));
    cardLayout.setMinimumWidth(width);

    // 3. Inflate the custom view
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View inflatedLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_customs, null, false);

    // 4. Set ID for the inflated view
    inflatedLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());

    // 5. (Optional) pick and change the elements in the custom view
    TextView otv = (TextView) inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    otv.setText("Welcome to my first app");


    /*
       You can avoid point 3, 4 and 5, if you do not want to infalte from existing layout, simply use:
     View inflatedLayout = new View(this.getContext());
    */

    // 6. (Optional) create new elements
    Button btn = new Button(this.getContext());
    btn.setId(View.generateViewId());
    btn.setText(R.string.custom);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                CharSequence text = "Hello from another toast!";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), text, duration);
                toast.show();
        }
    });

    TextView one = new TextView(this.getContext());
    one.setText("Device width is: ");
    one.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

    // 7. Locate the relative locations between the inflated element and the main Layout
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, inflatedLayout.getId());
    cardLayout.setLayoutParams(p);

    // 8. In the same way as of 7, locate the relative locations of the elements inside the main Layout itself.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, btn.getId());

   // 9. Add the inflated Layout, and all other elements to the main Layout
   cardLayout.addView(inflatedLayout);
   cardLayout.addView(btn);
   cardLayout.addView(one, lp);

   // 10. Add the main Layout to the class
   this.addView(cardLayout);  

    // 11. In the same way, you need to locate the returned CARD
    // in relative location in the view that calling it
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                               //  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                                  150);
    p1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.checkBox);
    this.setLayoutParams(p1);
}
```

4. (Optional) for the custom card drawable background, I used the below code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <shape
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
       android:width="2dp"
       android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <solid
       android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
       />

   <corners
       android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
       android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
       android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
       android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
   </shape>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        />

    <tk.zillion.app1.CustomViews.Card
        android:id="@+id/custom_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: :( no changes, same output